# NSBundle "not yet loaded" for existing path

Tags: ios, nsbundle

I'm trying to implement a way to change language inside the application.

I think I have it all figured it out, but for some reason the folder is not laded as a bundle

I have a folder called kh.lproj

```
  NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:newLanguage ofType:@"lproj"];

  if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path]) {
    bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:path];
    DLOG(@"Language: %@ from path %@ (%@)", newLanguage, path, bundle);
  }
```

The output of my dlog is

> Language: kh from path ......../F1AA1E74-A014-4331-BD1B-D05D0E54AFF3/console.app/kh.lproj
>   (NSBundle <......./F1AA1E74-A014-4331-BD1B-D05D0E54AFF3/console.app/kh.lproj>
>   (not yet loaded))

On both the iPhone and in the simulator (with different paths of course).

I have checked in the .app folder and the kh.lproj folder is there. (In lower case).

Does any one have an idea of why this is happening? If i try to load a file that doesn't exist it just ignores it and don't try to load it.

EDIT

If its to any help, when I'm using loadAndReturnError:(NSError) i get the message:

> NSLocalizedFailureReason=The bundle’s executable couldn’t be located.,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=The bundle “kh.lproj” couldn’t be loaded
>   because its executable couldn’t be located.,
>   NSBundlePath=......./A65E8399-6CDB-4CAE-9074-803125E78BBA/storeconsole.app/kh.lproj

What does this error message mean

Comment: Did you check whether it is marked for the right target? Sometimes adding resources lead not to automatic checks of the targets.

Comment: Yes, it's in the Copy Bundle Resources build phase. And as mentioned above, it's in the .app folder I get after compile, so it's definitely there

Comment: Sorry, then I have no clue so far.

Comment: I think loading only matters for using a bundle's executable code. If you're only using resources then you don't need to worry about it. https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Tasks/LoadingBundles.html

Comment: I met the same issue. I want to use the xib from bundle of own framework which doesn't include excutable code, still not working. Don't understand what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I get what I want anyway when calling

```
[bundle localizedStringForKey:key value:NULL table:nil];
```

Comment: The above code load always English language or your mobile language .

Comment: what's the key input?

Answer (score 0):

a possible pitfall is also, when the string file has a bug, like a missing semicolon or incomplete comment marker.

Xcode dont check the file for syntax errors.